# php $_GET dont take my document name with space so I cant unlink?

Tags: php, get, unlink

I have a problem I tried to retrieve a file with this code:

```
<?php


$path= "./uploadedfiles/";
$dir= dir($path);

while ($file = $dir->read()) {

        echo $file . "<a href=deletefile.php?file=$file>Delete</a><br>";         
}
$dir->close();
?>
```

and my deletefile.php

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];

echo $file;

$path =  'C:/wamp/www/project/uploadedfiles/'.$files;

if(unlink($path)){

    echo "File deleted";
}else{
    echo "Erro no uploaded";

}


?>
```

The problem is that with the line  $file = $_GET['file'];, if my files name is document name.pptx (space included) the $_GET just takes document, so my file never gets deleted, can someone help me? Help really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)() and [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)(), this should encode the space in the filename when passing it over the URL

So

```
echo $file . "<a href=deletefile.php?file=" . urlencode($file) . ">Delete</a><br>";
```

and

```
$file = urldecode($_GET['file']);
```

Comment: @ReOsless: if you also insist on quoting the attribute it get's my vote :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line:

```
echo $file . "<a href=deletefile.php?file=$file>Delete</a><br>";
```

To

```
echo $file . '<a href="deletefile.php?file='.urlencode($file).'">Delete</a><br>';
```

See [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php). It will convert your space to `%20`, so that it can be sent over GET.